# Suggestions for a Global Analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

can somebody tell me some good books or lecture notes in "global analysis" ? 
I am a newcomer in this subject. 
thanks in advance.

greetings
trito

Comment: Just to double check, what do *you* think is global analysis? My answer below is based on [Smale's definition](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316777) of the study of "differential equations ... on manifolds and vector bundles". If you have any special topics within the confines of global analysis that your want to learn, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I warmly recommend [Ramanan's *Global Calculus*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Global_calculus.html?id=1INoRKtgndcC&redir_esc=y) , an amazingly elegant book in the glorious tradition  of Tata Institute mathematics. It is about global analysis exactly  in the sense described by Willie, and written by a great mathematician.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg +1 for the mention of tradition of Tata Institute Mathematics! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic text on global analysis is Richard Palais' *Foundations of Global Non-linear Analysis*.

A more recent one is Kriegl and Michor's *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis*, which has the advantage of being [freely available on the author's website](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/listpubl.html#books).